# Error with p:commandbutton validating form

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces, process

I have a form with two p: commandbutton to user request system, both buttons perform the same action, because it has a p: accordeonpanel both buttons the user requested to post the information from the beginning or end of the page . The first button is properly validating the two components I am indicating, but the second button at the bottom of the page to do so is what makes me clean fields and p: selectOneMenu, as if making a "reset". Any idea of the problem? Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template=" ./../../../WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:define name="left">
    <ui:include src="#{bundle.LeftMenuSite}">
    </ui:include>  
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content_altern">
    <h3>#{bundle.SitSrtInfoTitle}</h3>
    <h:form id="gralForm" prependId="false">
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" style="float:right;" id="insertDataSRT0" process="@this,accPanel:mainInfoRF,accPanel:panelGridMap" update="accPanel:mainInfoRF accPanel:panelGridMap" action="#{sitSrtInfoController.create}" value="#{bundle.SendData}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"/> 
        <br/><br/>
        <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="1" multiple="true" id="accPanel"> 
            <p:tab title="#{bundle.AccTabSrtList}" id="tabSRTList">
                <ui:include src="/admin/sites/sitSrtInfo/List.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="#{bundle.AccTabSrtInfo}" id="tabInfo">
                <p:messages globalOnly="true"  ></p:messages>

                <p:panelGrid id="panelGridMap" columns="4">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_siteId}"  />
                    <p:inputText  id="siteId" value="#{sRTGMapController.srtgMap.srtCode}"  required="true" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_latitude}"   style="text-align: right" />
                    <p:inputText id="latitude" value="#{sRTGMapController.srtgMap.latitude}"  required="true" style="width:100px"  />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_longitude}"  style="width:50px" />
                    <p:inputText id="longitude" value="#{sRTGMapController.srtgMap.longitude}"  required="true" style="width:100px"   />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_srRadius}" />
                    <p:inputText id="srRadius" value="#{sRTGMapController.srtgMap.radius}"  required="true"  />
                    <h:outputLabel value=" "  style="width:50px" />
                    <h:outputLabel value=" "  style="width:50px" />
                    <p:commandButton process="panelGridMap" value="#{bundle.ViewPosition}" oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) dlg.show()" action="#{sRTGMapController.createModel}" update="dlg panelGridMap" icon="ui-icon-pin-s" />  
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg" modal="false"  styleClass="div-left" >  
                    <p:gmap id="myMap" center="#{sRTGMapController.center}" fitBounds="false"   zoom="18" type="HYBRID"  
                            styleClass="viewGMap" model="#{sRTGMapController.circleModel}" />  
                </p:dialog>  
                <p:panelGrid    id="mainInfoRF">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_dateReq}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:calendar id="dateReq" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.dateReq}" navigator="true"  required="true" readonlyInput="true"  >
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </p:calendar>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_priority}"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="priority" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.priority}"  required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.priority.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_typeSite}"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="typeSite" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.typeSite}" required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.typeSite.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_region}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="region" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.region}" required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.region.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_cluster}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="cluster" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.cluster}"   required="true"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_year}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="year" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.year}"  required="true"  />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_srVersion}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column> <p:inputText id="srVersion" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.srVersion}"  required="true"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column> <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_datum}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column> <p:selectOneMenu id="datum" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.datum}" required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.datum.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column> <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_morphology}"/> </p:column>
                        <p:column><p:selectOneMenu  id="morphology" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.morphology}" required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.morphology.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                        <p:column> <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_colDesign}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="colDesign" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.colDesign}" required="true"  /></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column> <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_ownerId}"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column>  <p:selectOneMenu id="ownerId" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.ownerId}"  required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.owner.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                        <p:column>  <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_oveDesign}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="oveDesign" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.oveDesign}" required="true"  /></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>  <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_existSiteIdCms}"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column> <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="existSiteIdCms" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.existSiteIdCms}" required="true" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>  <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_existSiteName}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>  <p:inputText id="existSiteName" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.existSiteName}"  required="true"  /></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>   <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_hubSite}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="hubSite" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.hubSite}" required="true"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column>   <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_fiberMw}"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column>   <p:selectOneMenu id="fiberMw" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.fiberMw}"  required="true" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{staticCatsController.fiberMW.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
                                               itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>      <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_mwRepeater}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mwRepeater" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.mwRepeater}" required="true" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>     <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_generatedBy}"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column>     <p:inputText id="generatedBy" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.generatedBy}"  required="true"  /></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>     <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_receivedBy}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>     <p:inputText id="receivedBy" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.receivedBy}"   required="true"  /></p:column>
                        <p:column>      <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_statusReg}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="statusReg" value="#{secCompaniesController.selected.statusReg}"  required="true" /></p:column>
                    </p:row> 
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_country}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>     <p:selectOneMenu id="countryId" value="#{geoCitiesController.countrySelected}" required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{geoCountriesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                                <p:ajax listener="#{geoCitiesController.statesByCountryId}" update="stateId" /> 
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                        <p:column>    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_state}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>    <p:selectOneMenu id="stateId" value="#{geoCitiesController.stateSelected}"    required="true" >
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectState}" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{geoCitiesController.statesAvailable}"/>
                                <p:ajax listener="#{geoCitiesController.citiesByStateId()}" update="cityId" /> 
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>   <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_city}" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>   <p:selectOneMenu id="cityId" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.city}"  required="true" >
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectCity}" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{geoCitiesController.citiesAvailable}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                        <p:column>    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_market}"/></p:column>
                        <p:column>     <p:selectOneMenu id="market" value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.market}"  required="true"  >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{geoMarketsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="1">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.SitSrtInfoLabel_comments}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column colspan="3">    
                            <p:inputTextarea value="#{sitSrtInfoController.selected.comments}"  id="comments" rows="6" cols="45"  maxlength="400" autoResize="false" required="true"/> 
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <br/>
            </p:tab>  
            <p:tab title="#{bundle.AccTabSrtRF}" id="tabRFSRT">
                <ui:include src="/admin/sites/sitSrtRf/Create.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="#{bundle.AccTabSrtTrans}" id="tabTransSRT">
                <ui:include src="/admin/sites/sitSrtTrans/Create.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
        <br/><br/> 
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" style="float:right;" id="insertDataSRT1" process="@this,accPanel:mainInfoRF,accPanel:panelGridMap" update="accPanel:panelGridMap accPanel:mainInfoRF" action="#{sitSrtInfoController.create}" value="#{bundle.SendData}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"/> 

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content_middle"> 
</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the reset button, reset does everything.
So if I understand well enough that you do the reset button that calls a bean where it reset all the pulsed variable after this does the update of the @form

Comment: Hi, (sorry for my english, is nothing good), no, the info should be saved to a database. The first button (on top of the page), validate and send information perfectly, but second  button (on bottom of the page) should do the same action (the user requested that both do it), just validate some fields and reset the selectonemenu elements. And, as you can see, both buttons are defined by the exactly same code, only change for basic reasons the ID.

Comment: hey,
i don't understand your problem, please tell me the id of the button don't work and what's the role of this button, and if you can write the beans code.

Comment: Hi @sghaierali, thanks for answer, sorry for my bad english. Both buttons should have absolutly the same behaviour, the first button ("insertDataSRT0") works perfectly, but second button ("insertDataSRT1") doesn't, my question is why not even the second button performs validation, despite having exactly the same code as the first, obviously changing its ID. Does this have to do because one is located before the items to validate and the other after the elements? Both are within the same FORM.. Why are two buttons with the same behaviour? Because the user has requested the system this way.

Comment: i see the problem is in process attribut, if you debug the first click button you see the second button is called,  the order it s not important. if you like use process use styleclass is good, I'm not sure the error you got is because of process attribute. if you like give me the beans code and i see it more